# Css animation - stop and revert animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, frontend, keyframe

I want my custom element to move to the right for 200px when clicking a button. So the element starts moving on click. When in the animation I want to be able to click the button again to stop and let the element have an animated return to initial state (reverse animation from the current state).

I accomplished this with css transitions:

```js
var state = false;
var button = document.getElementById("but");

button.onclick = clickA;

function clickA(){
  
  state = !state;
  
  var el = document.getElementById("el");
  if (state) el.setAttribute("class", "animatedElement open");
  else el.setAttribute("class", "animatedElement");
}
```

```css
.animatedElement {
  padding-left: 0px;
  transition: padding-left 5s;
}

.open {
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="but">Click</button>
<div id="el">element</div>
```

So on click I just toggle the `.open` class on the component.

I want to know if this is possible to do with css animations? I tried this:

```js
var state = false;
var button = document.getElementById("but");

button.onclick = clickA;

function clickA(){
  
  state = !state;
  
  var el = document.getElementById("el");
  if (state) el.setAttribute("class", "animatedComponent-open");
  else el.setAttribute("class", "animatedComponent-close");
}
```

```css
@keyframes animationOpen {
  0% {padding-left: 0px;}
  100% {padding-left: 200px;}
}
.animatedComponent-open {
  animation: animationOpen 3s normal forwards;
}
    
@keyframes animationClose {
  0% {padding-left: 0px;}
  100% {padding-left: 200px;}
}
.animatedComponent-close {
  animation: animationClose 3s reverse forwards;
}
```

```html
<button id="but">Click</button>
<div id="el">element</div>
```

But this doesn't revert open animation when clicked in the middle of animation, but jumps to the final state and then plays close animation from beginning.

Answer (score 2):

As the keyframes have a starting point and and ending point, so they will start from those positions no matter where where the current position of the element is. Since you are using js to toggle, transitions are the way to go. Animations are just complicating it more without any benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

I am sure this article will have the exact answer for you. There are many work arounds to get the current keyframe values at an animation playstate of pause.
Then with these values you can use the animate api to build a reverse animation.
If you can pass the reverse animation the pause keyframe values as starting-position values. Then you can set your animation end keyframes to paddingLeft:0px - just how it started.

This will solve the unwanted jumping to the end of the animation.